# Sound not playing with cordova and Phaser

Tags: android, cordova, phaser-framework

I followed a simple tutorial to create a game using Phaser and I have modified all the files and directories to make it work with cordova so that it works on Android. The problem is the sound that plays on browser is not playing on phone. I read that I should use the cordova Media API so I added it but I get the error "Media is not defined" when running the game.
This is the order in which I link to the js files in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

I'm creating the audio variable in the preload function of phaser like so:

```
preload: function() { 
    var audio = new Media('/android_asset/www/img/assets/jump.wav');
}
```

And in the jump function:

```
jump: function() {
    window.audio.play();
}
```

I can't understand what's the problem.

Comment: did you load it after device ready?

Comment: Are you talking about cordova.js? I'm not using the deviceready event which is default in cordova because Phaser doesn't need it.

Comment: but you use cordova api!  any cordova Api can be used only after device ready

Comment: So I should make a function which contains all the phaser code and call it in the deviceready event?

Comment: in my case, my index.html can be run on desktop browser or mobile browser or as an native app. run on Android or iPhone.  if I checked that (by cheching the http header) it is run as a native app.  I immediately check the device ready status Before i call any Api related codes.

Comment: I just put the part that cordova puts by default in index.js, that with the onDeviceReady function. I tried writing in this function a call to a function containing all the phaser code but it didn't work. After this, I tried leaving the phaser code out and just put a return in the onDeviceReady. Now the game starts and there are no errors in the console but still there's no sound.

Comment: can u var the audio globally inside index.html without the =.  then assign value to audio inside device ready.

Comment: then call a function declared inside index.html to play the sound

Comment: omg it's wav!  did u try mp3! a month ago i've problem using wav then i change it to mp3

Comment: It was the deviceready event that wasn't correctly set. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to integrate cordova plugin native sound with phaser js.
1. create a cordova project
2. add android platform
3. add plugin native sound

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativeaudio

to use it:
you also need to play start and stop loop sound to avoid error
here is small code i capture for you:

declare all global variable and Phaser game state on index.html file
'

```
var HomeState;
var LevelState;
    var GameOver;
    var GameWinner;
    var GameState;
    var CreditState;
    var ShareState;
    var SellState;

    var app;
    enter code here

create app  class object
create 3 main method for audio function

    playNativeSoundLoop:function(keyid)
    {
     window.plugins.NativeAudio.loop(keyid);

    },
    playNativeSound:function(keyid)
    {
     window.plugins.NativeAudio.play(keyid);        
    },
    stopNativeSound:function(keyid)
    {
     window.plugins.NativeAudio.stop(keyid);
    //window.plugins.NativeAudio.unload(keyid);  
    }
'
```

i can give your full code by download this sample game, that prove what i mention. This game made pure by phaser js and cordova

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.s2team.blindmaze&hl=en